# .htaccess code that uses gethostbyname() to redirect specific nameservers

Tags: .htaccess, dns

Someone else's domain is permanently redirecting to my domain. When I block the bad boy's IP address with `deny 1.2.3.4` in .htaccess, my website throws up a `…403 Forbidden error`.

Blocking the referrer with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} baddomain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

also doesn't work, I inevitably end up blocking my own domain.

What code do I need to put in .htaccess to redirect incoming traffic that originates from a particular name server? Someone suggested `gethostbyname()`, can anyone please give me the whole code?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly is this other domain "permanently redirecting" to your domain? If it is literally a 301 HTTP redirect (as you are suggesting) then there is nothing you can do since the request is not actually coming from that "domain", but the client that requested that domain. "originates from a particular name server" - "name server"? That's not a "redirect"? "Someone suggested gethostbyname()" - who suggested? This is not an Apache/.htaccess function, but I don't see how that is supposed to help anyway? It's also curious how all your attempts seem to end up blocking your own domain??!

Comment: This command 

[System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create('http://baddomain.com').GetResponse().ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri

shows the bad domain is pointing to my domain. I mentioned the name server that is hosting the bad domain before it's redirected to my domain. gethostbyname() was suggested by a Stackoverflow moderator when I previously posted my question in the wrong place. Sadly, I'm not enough of an expert to judge on the suggestion. 

Is there a way to block the incoming traffic based on the name servers (ns123.cloudhosting.com) where the bad domain is hosted?